# How do I create auto resizeable button and text using jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build

I am trying to create an android mobile application using phonegap and jQuery Mobile. I've created the interface of my app, created some buttons and some other basic stuffs. This runs into android flawlessly. The interface, buttons are fine in my tab. But when I installed it into another android device of lower screen size the interface became awkward. The button size was all ok, all the buttons had equal height and width but the button text was not fitted with the button width. Text of longer length doesn't appear in full length. After showing some character, other characters goes under "..." like-"Digital Ce..." here is a screen shot-

[image]

But I want the interface to be like this-

[image]
I want the button text to be resized according to button width, button height may be automatically extended to hold the full text.

I've code the the grid buttons as follows:

```
<div class="ui-grid-b my-breakpoint">
  <div class="ui-block-a"><button type="button" data-theme="c"> <img src="res/icon/android/business.png" height="45"><br>Business</button></div>
  <div class="ui-block-b"><button type="button" data-theme="c"> <img src="res/icon/android/digital_center.png" height="45"><br>Digital Center</button></div> 
  <div class="ui-block-c"><button type="button" data-theme="c"> <img src="res/icon/android/employment.png" height="45"><br>Employment</button></div>     
</div>
```

This problem also happens with the other button of other pages:
[image]

Here is the code of these buttons:

```
    <form action="http://www.frs-bd.com/">
        <input data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" type="submit" value="Fertilizer Recommendation">
    </form>

    <form action="http://www.knowledgebank-brri.org/">
        <input data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" type="submit" value="Bangladesh Rice Knowledge Bank">
    </form>

    <form action="http://www.frs-bd.com/">
        <input data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" type="submit" value="Fertilizer Recommendation">
    </form>
```

Now how do I fix it? How do I make the button text auto resizeable according to button width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.ui-btn {  
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```

> [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/n98m7m88/)